# Java Script Regex ^[^0]\d{1,4}$

Tags: javascript, regex

I want to match a number with 1 to 4 digits which doesn't start with 0, using a regular expression in JavaScript. I tried:

```
^[^0]\d{1,4}$
```

But this doesn't work.

Is there any problem with `{1,4}` in JavaScript?
It should check digits are matched 1 to 4 times, shouldn't it?

Comment: `[^0]` means - any character other than `0`

Comment: `^\d{1,4}$` should work for you. Tested with http://regexpal.com/

Comment: @nilsK and i don't want first digit be 0

Comment: Please be more precisely with your questions. Take your time, the people answering your question are doing it too. No offense, but if you are asking yourself why you got down votes, this might be your anser.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

## Why your regex doesn't work

`^[^0]\d{1,4}$` means anything apart from 0 followed by 1 to 4 digits. Therefore the following will match:

- A6789
- Z0

---

## The solution

If you want any 1 to 4 digit number but without starting 0s you want:

`^(?!0)\d{1,4}$`

This will match:

- 1234
- 5
- 99

But not:

- 0123
- 005
- 12345
- Z123

---

## Why the solution works

`(?!0)` is a Negative Lookahead which asserts the string doesn't start with the contained pattern, in this case `0`.

Comment: Or just `^[1-9]\d{0,3}$`, which is both faster and easier to understand. But I see why you choose a negative lokahead. But there's never only 1 right solution, and you deserve +1 for a different method.

Comment: Fair enough @IsmaelMiguel, but I personally find the negative lookahead easier to read. But +1 for another perfectly sound method.

Comment: I am asking myself: why is 'any of these' faster then 'not this'?

Comment: @nilsK What do you mean?

Comment: In my understanding, I might be wrong though, If '[1-9]' does a lower/bigger then match, it needs to make two checks; '(?!0)' needs only one. Why is your solution faster? Maybe I missed something ;)

Comment: @nilsK `[1-9]` checks if the character is within that character range. Which is equivalent to `(?:1|2|3|4|5|6|7|8|9)`, but faster. A lookahead has adicional performance implications, since it has to take a peek at the next character(s), using a capture group to match the pattern in it, to only then match the next pattern. What do you think it is faster? Check if, for example, `6` is between `1` and `9` or see if it is not a `0` and then check if it is between `0` and `9` (`\d` is equivalent to `[0-9]`)?

Answer (score 6):

Your regex is incorrect. There is no problem in Javascript.

Here is the regex you want:

```
^[1-9]\d{0,3}$
```

Basically:

- `[1-9]` matches any number that isn't `0`
- `\d{0,3}` will match up to 3 more numbers, from 0 to 9

The regex you have will match these:

- `Z000`
- `.123`
- `-111`
- ...

Answer (score 2):

Please show us the code that does not work.

This is what you are doing now:

- One character that is not `0`
- One to four characters that are decimal
  numbers

So you can produce 5 digits. Yout gotta correct that. We can help you if you provide code and context.